# Passing ng-model from view to controller angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass value like this from view to controller in angular js of this form. I do not wish to hardcode it in this way. How could it be done in proper manner?

```js
angular.module('user').controller('UsersController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Users',
 function($scope, $stateParams, Orders) {
  $scope.create = function() {
   var user = new Users({
    child: [
     { columnA: child[0].columnA, columnB: child[0].columnB, columnC: child[0].columnC },
     { columnB: child[1].columnA, columnB: child[1].columnB, columnC: child[1].columnC },
     ...
     { columnC: child[10].columnA, columnB: child[10].columnB, columnC: child[10].columnC }
    ]
   });
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<form data-ng-submit="create()">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[0].columnA">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[0].columnB">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[0].columnC">

  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[1].columnA">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[1].columnB">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[1].columnC">
  
  ......

  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[10].columnA">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[10].columnB">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="child[10].columnC">
</form>
```

It would be better if an reusable directive that may perform above function.

```
$scope.create = function() {
    child: toJSON(child);
}

function toJSON(var a) {
    //automatically search through the view for ng-model with child[index].columnName and change to the form above.
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.Have you tried using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @charlietfl Hi i have no problem with the view currently. This is a post form from view to controller where user submit the form.How could i simplified the assigning data-ng-model process in controller in this case?

Comment: Still not understanding the issue. You do realize that `ng-model` will automatically create all the objects you have in view if they don't already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote out a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUe9JyzCvmpGT06reV9F?p=preview) that demonstrates one way to do something similar to what you are trying to do using angular practices.

You'll note that I eliminated all the duplication in the view by using `ng-repeat`, and have made the number of `child` elements dynamic.  I initialized the `users` object with an empty array, but you could easily initialize the object with data from the server.

Note also that changes to the form are *immediately* reflected in the object, meaning in the `create()` function, you can serialize the `users` object, not the form values.  In practice, this is probably not necessary, however, since if you use an angular library like `$http`, serialization to and from JSON is performed automatically.

```js
$scope.users = {
  child: [{}]
};
$scope.create = function() {
   var data = angular.toJson($scope.users);
   alert(data);
};

$scope.addUser = function() {
  $scope.users.child.push({});
};
```

```html
<form ng-submit="create()">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users.child">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.columnA">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.columnB">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.columnC">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<button ng-click="addUser()">Add New User</button>

<pre> {{users}}</pre>
```

The main takeaway from this, however, should be that the view and the controller work together to eliminate duplication and unnecessary references.  we are no longer referring to `child[0]` in the HTML, making the HTML more readable and maintainable.